# C++ : String + integer path

Tags: c++, string, path, int, srand

I'm pretty new to C++, so sorry if I asked something obvious.

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomID = (rand() % 100);

string path = "./Questions/" + randomID + ".quiz";
```

In /Questions there are .quiz Files that are named as random integer numbers like "1.quiz", "202.quiz", "13.quiz"

It doesn't work when I put the randomID in, how can I solve this?
The Error is in German so I don't think it will help you, it just says that `".quiz"` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string path = "./Questions/" + to_string(randomID) + ".quiz";
```

Answer (score 3):

random is an int there is no defined function `string operator+(string,int)`.  You could provide one, but I wouldn't suggest that.  You can however convert the number to a string.

If you are using c++ 11 you can use [to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)(int) if you are using c++03 [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is available

Comment: +1 There's also `boost::lexical_cast<int>`